# I would like to add a shortcut to sp-wrap-square in spacemacs

Tags: spacemacs, smartparens

I would like to extend the lisp editing shortcuts so `SPC k [` and `SPC k {` would wrap the current form in `[]` and `{}` respectively.

I don't know what I need to write in my spacemacs config to enable this only for the lisp editing buffers.

What I did so far:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'clojure-mode "k [" 'sp-wrap-square)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys-for-major-mode 'clojure-mode "k {" 'sp-wrap-curly)
```

But these add only in clojure mode and the shortcuts will be `, k [` and `, k {` instead of the desired `SPC k [` and `SPC k {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this:

```
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys (kbd "k [") 'sp-wrap-square)
(spacemacs/set-leader-keys (kbd "k {") 'sp-wrap-curly)
```